# Effectively wait for multiple messages

Tags: c#, performance, synchronization, task, messaging

Imagine you have a client and a server communicating via some kind of a message bus, which has this interface:

```
interface IBus {
   void Send(Message m);
   void Receive(Message m);
}
```

with `Message` being some POCO like this:

```
class Message {
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

So you can send a message via `Send` and when the response arrives the messaging infrastructure is going to invoke `Receive` method which essentially is just a callback. What I would like to do now is to write a method which will allow me to wait for response

```
Message WaitForResponse(Message request);
```

and use it like this:

```
var response = WaitForResponse(request);
Console.Write(response.Data);
```

I tried using `TaskCompletionSource` for it and it works great, but it requires `async\await` and I already got a lot of code written in this sync style. This code is now using `ManulResetEventSlim` objects stored in `ConcurrentDictionary` for synchronization, but it encounters performance issues when the number of requests waiting for response grow to a couple of hundreds (I assume because all threads are blocked with `manualResetEventSlim.Wait()`). I guess there should be a better way to do it which will require changes only to the implementation of `WaitForResponse` and will keep all method signatures untouched

Comment: This is exactly where `async` model should be used. Anything else ends up your own implementation of the concept (reinventing the wheel).

Comment: @Xaqron well, this looks like an interesting exercise, I'd like to try reinventing it at least for better understanding of how it's done

Comment: In that sense it is a very good idea. You may become one of the `Node.js` fans at the end.

Comment: "but it encounters performance issues when the number of requests waiting for response grow to a couple of hundreds" - yeah, this is pretty much exactly why `async`/`await` exists... so that you have lots of pending work items without needing lots of threads. Unfortunately, yes: it does require a different coding approach.

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah, this works great, however I wonder how people managed to solve such issues in pre-async era (e.g. .NET2.0). I should still be theoretically able to achieve acceptable (say for 10_000 requests pending in my question) performance with older .NET versions or languages without async-like constructs, right?

Comment: I would say that 10k pending requests is a bad design async or not. Maybe you should just read on the queue and handle what ever message comes in, instead of 10k times waiting for a specific message to come in. With 10k waits, even if they are async, you have a lot of overhead. I don't know how WaitForResponse works but if it is `if (messageMatches) return result;` then you will have 10k such ifs for each incoming message. That's O(N*10k).

Comment: @usr with `async` it's fine even for millions of requests. `WaitForResponse` now creates `ManualResetEventSlim` for each request and just blocks with `ManualResetEventSlim.Wait()` until it receives signal with `ManualResetEventSlim.Set()`

Comment: What does WaitForResponse do? If it issues IO then millions are definitely not fine with async. The kernel is not made to handle millions of outstanding IOs. It really depends on what WaitForResponse does.

Comment: @usr this can be considered to be in-memory only for the sake of keeping this example simple, you can think of `WaitForResponse` to be doing this:
`var mre = new ManualResetEventSlim();
            StoreInDictionary(mre);
            Send(request);
            if (mre.WaitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout: 1000, exitContext: true))
                return request;`

Comment: OK, that should be feasible. Just wanted to check because it sounded suspicious. Can you not just use a `TaskCompletionSource<object>` as the event? Purely in memory and gives you a ready made task.

Comment: @usr not sure this will make any difference considering I can't `await` it but will rather have to do `taskCompletionSource.Task.Wait()`

Comment: It seems I have a bit of trouble comprehending this question, I apologize. I only now notice that you want to keep the sync style. In that case my diagnosis is that nothing can save you. This design forces waiting on a kernel event. I measured stuff like that a while ago. A few hundred such threads seem fine (although costly) but 10k makes the mouse jitter for example and performance starts to suck. I think this design is a dead end...